# Html div in div: older versions of native android browser does not limit image to container size

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, scaling, android-browser

I try to have a banner on top of my page(wordpress). On top of the banner should be a institution logo, limited to the size of the banner (I want other users to be able to substitute the banner). The theme is responsive
I got it to work with the code below, however in old "Android native browser" versions the institution logo is not limited to the banner but continues until the content area. I don't have many android devices to test, but this behavior definetly appears on Android 4.1 and seems fixed in 4.4.

Looking at my code, I think all I used is really old html stuff so this should already be supported by Android 4.1 browser.I don't have a clue why the behavior is as it is.

I would be thankful for a explanation. What could I do to fix the behavior for my site?
If it is not possible to realize this behavior for older android versions, would it be possible to detect the android version/ browser version (keyword user agent?) to detect if version is smaller than xxx.

I hope someone can help me, because I don't have a clue how to advance.

Html:

```
<div id="logo">
  <div>
    <img src="/images/banner.jpg"  height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" />
  </div>
  <div id="institution-logo" >
    <img src="/images/institution_logo.gif"  height="auto" width="auto"  style="max-height:100%; max-width:100%; left: 5%"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#institution-logo{
position:absolute;
top: 0px; 
left: 0%;
width:20%;
height: 100%;
padding: 2%;
}
```

Comment: Make sure #logo is position relative and that it has a width and a height.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Setting position relative, width and height of #logo solved the "Android specific behavior". However, using it I  didn't get it responsive. So the banner always stayed fixed size(width) and the rest of the page became narrower. I already had a try to fix this but until now did not get it to work.

Comment: use max-width:100% on both #logo and it's children.

Comment: Sorry, I got an error, editing, because I passed 5 minutes. That's why I copy it again.

I found out about this issue. Browser seem to react different on absoulte positioned div in relative div.
While firefox limits images to the parent container other browsers do not do this.

Solution was to overlay divs with equal size via z-index using background image for institution-logo (absolute positioning).

the container div for background image keeps constant ratio using
padding-bottom: [3/4]%; for aspect ratio of 4:3.
Works fine